# Different shipping amounts based on total amount of order in ubercart

Tags: php, drupal, ubercart

is there an option to offer different shipping amounts based on the total amount of the order in Ubercart ?  An example would be the following, if the order totaled:

- 0-$50 then shipping would be $50
- $50-$100 then shipping would be $125
- $100-$500 then shipping would be $1000

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any specific option for that, but in MARKUPS you can choose the **percentage**, which may give a close result of what you need.